# Using jQuery to insert rendered HTML into a text field

Tags: jquery, html, textbox

*Edited to make my actual goal more clear...*

Not sure if this is even possible without a lot of effort...

I have a text field where my users will be typing comments. I want to enable tagging a user by prefacing their name with the @ sign. I've put together some jQuery functions which poll the text field, wait until a @ sign is entered, then use a regex to grab the text after the @ sign and return a list of matching users. This is all working well.

My problem comes when the user selects one of the results -- I want to replace the "@username" in the textfield with some kind of formatted text. The goal is to provide
a way to visually distinguish the username in the textfield so users know it was properly processed as a tag. Is there any way to use formatting of any kind in a text field? Or is there another form element I could use that does support this?

Thanks

**Update:**
Searching around, I found this question: [jQuery textbox and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932177/jquery-textbox-and-html?rq=1)

It's recommended to that author that he use a div to display the rich HTML and use a hidden input to capture the text from the user. I suppose I could use AJAX to grab every keystroke on the textfield and update a div with the contents, but is this a lot of overhead? Any other solutions out there that would make sense in this situation?

Comment: I personally like how SO does it.. it just leaves it as the text "@Username".  It is then editable still and makes sense.

Comment: Have you considered applying the links in the backend instead of the frontend? e.g. your comment is stored as "blah blah @will blah blah", but then when you print the comment via PHP or whatnot you can do a preg_replace and insert the appropriate links. More valid, prevents the user from inserting malicious links, and works better overall.

Comment: @StefanH - I agree, but unfortunately the client wants it to "be clear to the user" that the text was recognized as a tag. I'm still trying to convince them that it is more trouble that it is worth, but figured I'd see if there was an easy solution out there I hadn't thought of...

Comment: @Will - yes, as I mentioned I don't really care about inserting the link in the textfield if I can find a way to visually distinguish the tag text...a different color, bold, anything like that would work.

Comment: I edited the question to remove the part about inserting the link into the textfield - I realized my end goal is just to make the tagged text stand out in some way, and I think the link part complicates the question without adding anything to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Update to your question is 100% correct.

Capturing key strokes is definitely the right approach however they way you implement it will determine the overhead.

I'd recommend waiting until you capture an @ symbol followed by X number of characters and then a space.  Once you read the space you can send an AJAX request.

Unless the user is typing a million @ tags I can't imagine it being a lot of requests.

Keep in mind some applications poll a server several times a second, this would be far less.

Comment: I've since convinced the client to abandon this "functionality" and just leave the tags alone in the text box. I then swap them out for links using jQuery on the submit. However, looks like this would be the best solution if I did need to display any kind of formatting in the text box itself. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jim, I would have just left this as a comment but I can not yet do that.  I have had to do something similar before and used a lightweight wysiwyg editor to do this.  It might be overkill for your situation, but maybe something to look into.

Answer (score -1):

please try like this.

```
var text = '<a href="users/username">username</a>'
var o = $(text);
```

Comment: This just provides the OP with an anchor object in javascript, this does not address any of their actual issues.